# Webmethods : [ISS.0085.9281] Http Error: 500 - Timeout

Tags: webmethods

We have a problem with our webmethods platform, in fact, we have errors:

> [ISP.0085.9998E] Exception -> com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceException:
>
> [ISS.0085.9281] Http Error: 500 - Timeout , And this on several
>   streams.

Knowing that the configured timeout is 120 seconds and the error occurs after 35 to 40 seconds.

We are working on webmethods 9.6, and we call a backend that uses SAP.

Comment: Any answer? It really blocks us

Answer (score 0):

This timeout is not at wM side but from a called web service.
This WS can be located from your SAP backend but can be also internal to your wM suite (for example, a call to MWS or to another IS in case of cluster).

Increasing IS logs related to webwervices call to obtain more details and ensure the source of this timeout.

Bye.